# why value of variable changed to *

Tags: t-sql

I have below 3 scenarios and get results. 2 of them is what I expected, but for the 3rd one, I could not understand.any idea about it?

```
declare @a char(3)
set @a='1003'
select @a----get 100
GO

declare @a char(3)
set @a=100
select @a----also get 100
GO


declare @a char(3)---or varchar(3)
set @a=1003
select @a----get * as result
```

Comment: Rather than fitting four digits into a three character string, the system helps you by indicating an overflow: `*`.

Comment: but if I declare the variable to nchar(3) or nvarchar(3), it will raiserror.

Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

Comment: The behavior is documented under [CAST and CONVERT: Truncating and rounding results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#truncating-and-rounding-results).

Comment: I've never run across this behavior. Thanks for adding it to the list of things to keep in the back of my mind! +1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the size of your `char`.

In your query:

```
declare @a char(3)---or varchar(3)
set @a=1003
select @a----get * as result
```

You used `char(3)`, which is too small for the data you are allocating to the variable.

Rather change it to :

```
declare @a char(4)
set @a=1003
select @a
```

As can be seen [here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9d6cb449346449d974d51125eb30312a)